# Django book Chapter 5 Database Engine setting

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm pretty sure I followed the procedures for this tutorial accurately but I'm still getting errors =/

Currently, my settings.py DATABASES looks like this

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql','sqlite3' or 'oracle'.      
        'NAME': 'mydb',     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'user',     # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'pwd',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',         # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',         # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

The tutorial tells me to have 'mysql' in ENGINE. However when I try to use the command 'python manage.py shell' I get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.mysql instead.
Error was: No module named mysql.base
```

This is why I have `django.db.backends.mysql` next to `ENGINE`.

After these settings, the tutorial tells me to type in these commands

```
'python manage.py shell'     <--- works fine

from django.db import connection      <--- works fine

cursor = connection.cursor()          <--- uh oh
```

After running the cursor command, I get this error

http://pastebin.com/8MtYq7rg

Not really sure what this means =/

When I try to run my server with `python manage.py runserver` I get this error. Not sure what this means either but the last error seems to be the same.

http://pastebin.com/91U3dz73

Also I looked up online to use `python manage.py dbshell` to test my DB access and this is the message I get.

`Error: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.`

I posted this problem on reddit to see if I could get any extra help. I hope some of this information provides extra help to this problem.

1. Type MySQL in a shell and see the result
2. Post how you installed MySQL. Did you make a table for Django to use already?
3. What OS are you using?

   1. Nothing happens when I type in MySQL in shell. When I type in the command 'python manage.py shell' then MySQL. I get an error "NameError: name 'MySQL' is not defined". When i type MySQL in terminal, it says MySQL: command not found
   2. How I installed MySQL was that I downloaded the file and then extracted where the tar file is located. Next I put the extracted folder into /home/Development directory. All my code is stored in /home/Development/djcode/mysite/mysite/
   3. I am using Ubuntu

*********UPDATE*********UPDATE******************************

So I believe that I was getting my error due to the fact that I didn't have MySQL installed/downloaded. What I had was MySQL-Python which isnt the same thing... But anyways, I downloaded/installed MySQL and ran python shell with 'python manage.py shell' then 'from django.db import connection' and then 'cursor = connection.cursor()'

However, I get the following error

OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'bradford'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Not sure what to do at this point =/

Comment: You don't appear to actually have MySQL running locally.

Comment: I posted my question on reddit haha in order to get more help. I was wondering if this would provide more information to the problem. 

    Type MySQL in a shell and see the result
    Post how you installed MySQL. Did you make a table for Django   to use already?
    What OS are you using?

Comment: The last error `Access denied` its because either you are using wrong username or password in your settings file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the right username and password. I'm supposed to use the root password and the username on my computer right?

Comment: PROBLEM IS FIXED!!! I had ot install MySQL and do a bunch of editing to the settings!!! woot! thanks everyone for the help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing [Python MySQLDB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have that downloaded

Comment: To test go into a python shell and type:

    import _mysql

You shouldn't see an error.

Comment: >>> import_MySQL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'import_MySQL' is not defined

=/

Comment: You forgot to put a space between 'import' and '_mysql'

Comment: Turns out he was missing MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine

You should use

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I've been using that code ever since terminal told me to haha but I still get the errors when I run the server or the cursor command =/

Comment: What is that $ before DATABASES?

Comment: It is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I was trying to add code in my post and told me to have a $ before my code haha I guess I did it wrong

Comment: what is the error message you are getting after using the `ENGINE` as I said?

Comment: Currently, what I have in engine is

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ....
    }
}

the tutorial tells me to run the command 'python manage.py shell'
then the tutorial tells me type this into python
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()

After the cursor command is when I get this error

http://pastebin.com/8MtYq7rg

Comment: Is your mysql database server running? Do you have a database named `mydb` in mysql in which the user `user` has access?

Comment: I cant run the mysql database server =/ It says  

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Answer (score 0):

This is response to your update. That is a MySQL error. MySQL sets up restrictions on how and where a user is able to access the database. You can find that documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html), but the **tl;dr** is that you need to make sure the user exists, the password is correct, and that you are connecting from the correct domain.